# Store Static Reference to Instance Method?

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I'd like to create a static array that contains delegates. I will use this array to look up the delegate that I need. For example:

```
class HandlerID
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Func<int, bool> Handler { get; set; }
}

protected const HandlerID[] HandlerIDs = {
    new SectionRenderer() { ID = SectionTypes.Type1, Handler = MyType1Handler },
    new SectionRenderer() { ID = SectionTypes.Type2, Handler = MyType2Handler },
    // Etc.
}

protected bool MyType1Handler(int arg)
{
    return false;
}

// Etc.
```

However, the assignments to `Handler` in the `HandlerID` array gives the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyType1Handler(int)'

I'd prefer the array is `const` so it doesn't have to be initialized for every instance of my class. Is there any way to store an instance method in a static array?

Comment: You can't make a `const` array.

Comment: What would you call what my code creates then?

Comment: A compiler error.  You mean to make a `static readonly` field.

Comment: It is a good question, Lippert blog material.  Lose the *const* to get some clarity, that's C++ thinking.  A delegate requires *two* bits of info, the method and the target.  The target is always inferred in C# from the context.  What C# will refuse is to infer it from a field initializer.  A wee bit silly because it already moves initializer code to the constructor.  Where it does not object to inferring the target.  C++/CLI works the same way, a bit surprising to me since it requires explicitly passing the target.  This is an object initialization order problem.

Comment: @Hans: The `this` keyword isn't available for inline initializers, which leads to the behavior seen here.  Using `this` before a constructor finishes is potentially troublesome, of course with a delegate is one of the safer examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't make sense.
When you call the delegates in the array, they need an instance of your class to operate on.

Therefore, you need a separate set of delegates for each class instance.

If the methods don't actually need an instance to operate on, you can make them `static`, which will fix the problem.

Alternatively, you can take the instance as a parameter to the delegate, and use a lambda expression that calls the method: `Handler = (instance, arg) => instance.MyType1Handler(arg)`

Comment: Unless there is some way to infer the instance delegate from information that's stored statically. That's the question. It seems like it might be possible, using reflection if nothing else.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  It's `static`, so there is no instance.

Comment: You could create open delegates and store them in a static array, then provide the instance at the call site.

Comment: You would have to do like `Handler = instance.MyType1Handler`. Like SLaks says, you need an instance to call on a non-static member.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, but you need to use Reflection to do that.  Lambda expressions are much simpler.

Comment: @SLaks: Obviously there is no instance with a static list. However, I will have an instance at the time I need to call it. If I have the method name, or whatever else information about the method, and the class instance, then in theory I have all the information needed to call the instance method. The question is if C# will support this somehow.

Comment: @Jonathan: You need to use a delegate that takes the instance as a parameter, either using a lambda expression or by calling `Delegate.Create` to create an open delegate.

Comment: @Ben: Yes, that sounds like what I'm looking for can you elaborate on what I'd store in the array, and how I'd provide the instance at call time?

Comment: As I explained in [my blog](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-3-c.html), .Net delegates store the target instance in a field inside the delegate.  You can't use that mechanism here.

Comment: @Jonathan: You would use a `Func<YourType, int, bool>` and call `Delegate.Create` without providing an instance.

Comment: @Jonathan: The lambda syntax is definitely the easy way to make that work.  Maybe some future version of the C# compiler will recognize this case and convert the lambda to an open delegate.

Comment: @SLaks: The last part of your edited answer seems to meets the requirements. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a `const` array in C#, try `readonly` which ensures the pointer to the array (the instance) will not change but as far as I know there is no way to declaratively prevent the elements from being changed.

Comment: @SLaks: Yes of course there are ways to do it, my point is that there is no *C# language* construct for constant arrays unlike say in C++ (and I suspect that was the author's intention).

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a delegate to a static function and you can't create a delegate to a function in an non existent object instance. However you can store the MethodInfo and at a later time invoke that on an instance.

```
 // Use MethodInfo instead of Func in HandlerId
 public MethodInfo Method { get; set; }

 // Create the static list of handlers
 protected static HandlerID[] HandlerIDs = {    
  new SectionRenderer() { ID = SectionTypes.Type1, Method = typeof(MyHandlersClass).GetMethod("MyType1Handler") },    
  new SectionRenderer() { ID = SectionTypes.Type2, Method = typeof(MyHandlersClass).GetMethod("MyType2Handler") },    
   // Etc.
  }

  // invoke at some point
  HandlersIds[0].Method.Invoke(aninstanceobject, new object[] { arg } );
```

Comment: "can't create a delegate to a static function": Wrong.  "can't create a delegate to a function without an instance": Wrong.  MethodInfo: Slow.

Comment: - 1/2 for me: "The creation of open instance and closed static delegates is not directly supported by Visual Basic, C++, or C# for delegate constructors. Instead, use one of the Delegate.CreateDelegate method overloads that specifies MethodInfo objects, such as Delegate.CreateDelegate(Type, Object, MethodInfo, Boolean)."

Comment: That's correct, and calling `CreateDelegate` is well worthwhile, since calling the resulting delegate is several orders of magnitude faster than using `MethodInfo.Invoke`.  Also note that what MSDN says is that there's no syntax in C# for creating a closed delegate with a static method.  Creating an open delegate with a static method is easy, but your answer calls it impossible.